# How to refresh Wicket DataTable after submitting the Search button

Tags: search, button, datatable, refresh, wicket

I would like to refresh the Wicket DataTable after submitting the Search button.
Here is the code:

```
public class SearchPanel extends Panel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SearchService searchService;

    public SearchPanel(String id,final SearchService searchService) {
        super(id);
        this.searchService = searchService;
        add(new SearchForm("searchForm"));
    }

    private class SearchForm extends Form {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String searchString;

        public SearchForm(String id) {
            super(id);
            add(new TextField("searchString", new PropertyModel(this, "searchString")));
        }

        public void onSubmit() {
            PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
            searchService.findByTitleProperty(params.get("searchString").toString());
        }

        public String getSearchString() {
            return searchString;
        }

        public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
            this.searchString = searchString;
        }
    }
}
```

And my "Home Page" is the following:

```
public class BooksTablePage extends WebPage implements SearchService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @SpringBean
    private BookService service;
    private List<IColumn<BookDto, String>> columns;
    private SortableBookDtoDataProvider sortableBookDtoDataProvider;
    private DataTable table;

    public BooksTablePage() {

        add(new SearchPanel("searchPanel",this));

        columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<BookDto, String>>();

        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("ID"), "id"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("ISBN"), "isbn"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("TITLE"), "title"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("AUTHOR"), "author",
            "author"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(new Model<String>("COPIES"), "copies",
            "copies"));

        //sortableBookDtoDataProvider = new SortableBookDtoDataProvider(service,"Brave");
        sortableBookDtoDataProvider = new SortableBookDtoDataProvider(service);
        table = new DataTable("datatable", columns, sortableBookDtoDataProvider, 3);
        table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, (ISortStateLocator) table.getDataProvider()));
        add(table);

    }

    @Override
    public void findByTitleProperty(String value) {
        System.out.println("Search string: "+value);
        sortableBookDtoDataProvider = new SortableBookDtoDataProvider(service,value);
        table = new DataTable("datatable", columns, sortableBookDtoDataProvider, 3);
        table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, (ISortStateLocator) table.getDataProvider()));
        this.replace(table);
    }
}
```

}

The SearchService is the following:

```
public interface SearchService {

    public void findByTitleProperty(String value);

}
```

This is the BooksTablePage.html

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.3-strict.dtd">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Wicket Library Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <span wicket:id="searchPanel"></span>
  <table wicket:id="datatable"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

And the SortableBookDtoDataProvider:

```
public class SortableBookDtoDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<BookDto, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static List<BookDto> list = new ArrayList<BookDto>();

    private SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator comparator = new SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator();

    public SortableBookDtoDataProvider(BookService service) {
        list.addAll(service.findAll());
        setSort("author", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    }

    public SortableBookDtoDataProvider(BookService service,String title) {
        list.addAll(service.findByTitle(title));
        setSort("author", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<BookDto> iterator(long first, long count) {
        List<BookDto> newList = new ArrayList<BookDto>(list);
        Collections.sort(newList, comparator);
        return newList.subList(safeLongToInt(first), safeLongToInt(first + count)).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<BookDto> model(final BookDto object) {
        return Model.of(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSort(String property, SortOrder order) {
        super.setSort(property, order);
    }

    public int safeLongToInt(long l) {
        if (l < Integer.MIN_VALUE || l > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                (l + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value.");
        }
        return (int) l;
    }

    class SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator implements Comparator<BookDto>, Serializable {
        public int compare(final BookDto b1, final BookDto b2) {
            PropertyModel<Comparable> model1 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(
                b1, getSort().getProperty());
            PropertyModel<Comparable> model2 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(
                b2, getSort().getProperty());

            int result = model1.getObject().compareTo(model2.getObject());

            if (!getSort().isAscending()) {
                result = -result;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What exactly does not work? Does your data provider contain the correct data when re-rendering the page? Did you debug the data provider - Is the rendering really using the correct (new) instance of the data provider and the data table?

Comment: On second thought, it really must have something to do with your data provider. Please provide the code and some more info about what you have already tried / what you found out during debugging.

Comment: To complete the sample program I attache the missing HTML file and the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't use Ajax submit for your form Wicket will repaint the whole page together with the DataTable.

If you need to use Ajax submit then you just need to do `target.add(dataTable)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SortableBookDtoDataProvider extends SortableDataProvider<BookDto, String> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static List<BookDto> list = new ArrayList<BookDto>();

private SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator comparator = new SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator();

public SortableBookDtoDataProvider(BookService service) {
    list.addAll(service.findAll());
    setSort("author", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
}

public SortableBookDtoDataProvider(BookService service,String title) {
    list.addAll(service.findByTitle(title));
    setSort("author", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
}

@Override
public Iterator<BookDto> iterator(long first, long count) {
    List<BookDto> newList = new ArrayList<BookDto>(list);
    Collections.sort(newList, comparator);
    return newList.subList(safeLongToInt(first), safeLongToInt(first + count)).iterator();
}

@Override
public long size() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public IModel<BookDto> model(final BookDto object) {
    return Model.of(object);
}

@Override
public void setSort(String property, SortOrder order) {
    super.setSort(property, order);
}

public int safeLongToInt(long l) {
    if (l < Integer.MIN_VALUE || l > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
                (l + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value.");
    }
    return (int) l;
}

class SortableBookDtoDataProviderComparator implements Comparator<BookDto>, Serializable {
    public int compare(final BookDto b1, final BookDto b2) {
        PropertyModel<Comparable> model1 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(
                b1, getSort().getProperty());
        PropertyModel<Comparable> model2 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(
                b2, getSort().getProperty());

        int result = model1.getObject().compareTo(model2.getObject());

        if (!getSort().isAscending()) {
            result = -result;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is the WicketApplication file

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

public WicketApplication(){

}

@Override
public Class<BooksTablePage> getHomePage() {
    return BooksTablePage.class; 
}

@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();
    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));

}
```

}

Comment: Hi David! The expected beahviour should be when I click the Search button It searches according the search field.If it contains nothing it should gives back the full list,if it contains some data it searches according to it.Right now whatever info I give in the search filed  nothing appears in the list.Furthermore I should use AJAX button not to refresh tho whole page after each serach, just the list part of the page.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was now able to run your code, and the data table actually does update, it just appends all new search results to the old ones. The reason for this is that your list in the data provider is static:

```
private static List<BookDto> list = new ArrayList<BookDto>();
```

So even though you throw away your data provider and create a new one after each search:

```
sortableBookDtoDataProvider = new SortableBookDtoDataProvider(service,value);
table = new DataTable("datatable", columns, sortableBookDtoDataProvider, 3);
table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, (ISortStateLocator) table.getDataProvider()));
this.replace(table);
```

...this new data provider for the new data table is still using the same list of books. Just remove the `static` for the `list` member of your `SortableBookDtoDataProvider`, and the update should work.